# How to setImage of each words translate into one to another by using imageArray

Tags: java, arrays, swing

I made 5 java classes that their goals were to Translate English into French and to setup the image of each words writing in the Jfield1 when you click on the Jbutton.
My applet arrive to translate each English words writing in JField1 into French words in JField2. And I add two more Classes(ImageImplement and ImageInFrame) for setting up the image But unfortunately nothing work. And I really don’t know how to use imageArray.
Please help me!!!

I am sorry my english is not so good.

THIS IS MY APPLET

My first Class is StringArrayEnglishWord

public class StringArrayEnglishWords extends JPanel {

```
String[] names;
Graphics2D g2d;

public StringArrayEnglishWords(){
    EnglishWords();
    // drawNames();
}

public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
}

public void EnglishWords(){

    names=new String[16];
    names[0]="Tomatoes";
    names[1]="Chairs";
    names[2]="Car";
    names[3]="Computer";
    names[4]="Flowers";
    names[5]="Family";
    names[6]="Sister";
    names[7]="Husband";
    names[8]="God";
    names[9]="Book";
    names[10]="Watch";
    names[11]="Pencil";
    names[12]="Bottle";
    names[13]="Map";
    names[14]="Wife";
    names[15]="Bag";


}

public void drawNames(){
    for (int i=0; i<names.length; i++){
        g2d.drawString(names[i], 50, (1+i)*16);
    }
}

   public int indexOfWord(String userInput)
{
    for(int i=0;i<names.length;i++)
    {
        if(userInput.equals(names[i])){return i;}

    }
    return -1;
}
```

}

My second classes is StringArrayFrenchWords:

public class StringArrayFrenchWords extends JPanel {

```
String[] names2;
Graphics2D g2d;

public StringArrayFrenchWords(){
    FrenchWorld();
    // drawNames();

}

public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
}

public void FrenchWorld(){

    names2=new String[16];
    names2[0]="Tomate";
    names2[1]="Chaise";
    names2[2]="Voiture";
    names2[3]="Ordinateur";
    names2[4]="Fleurs";
    names2[5]="Familles";
    names2[6]="Soeur";
    names2[7]="Epoux, Mari";
    names2[8]="Dieu";
    names2[9]="Livre";
    names2[10]="Montre, Regarder";
    names2[11]="Crayon";
    names2[12]="Bouteille";
    names2[13]="Carte,plan";
    names2[14]="Femmme";
    names2[15]="Sac";


}
public void drawNames(){
    for (int i=0; i<names2.length; i++){
        g2d.drawString(names2[i], 50, (1+i)*16);
    }
}
```

}

My third Classe is extend Japplet (Translator):

public class Translator extends JApplet implements ActionListener {

```
String StringField1, StringImage;
StringArrayEnglishWords Englishw;
StringArrayFrenchWords Frenchw;

ImageInJframe img;
ImageImplement Images;
Image Image;

JButton[] buttons;
JComboBox[] comboBoxes;
JButton TranslateButton;


JPanel JPanel0,JPanel1;
JPanel buttonPanel;
JPanel comboBoxesPanel;
JTextField field1,field2;
ImageIcon Imageicon;
JLabel ImageLabel;


public void init(){

    setUpFields();

    Englishw=new StringArrayEnglishWords();
    Frenchw=new StringArrayFrenchWords();
    img = new ImageInJframe(); // this was for set up the image
    setUpimages();// for setup image too
}


public  void setUpFields() {
    TranslateButton = new JButton("TranslateButton");
    field1 = new JTextField(10);

    field2 = new JTextField(10);
    field2.setEditable(false);


    JPanel0 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

    JPanel0.add(field1);

    TranslateButton.addActionListener(this);

    field1.addActionListener(this);

    field2.addActionListener(this);

    JPanel0.add(TranslateButton);

    JPanel0.add(field2);


    add(JPanel0, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

}
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);


}


public void setUpimages() {//setUp images too

    ImageLabel.setIcon((Icon) img);

    JPanel1 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());


    JPanel1.add(ImageLabel);

    add(JPanel1, BorderLayout.CENTER);


}


@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if (e.getSource() == TranslateButton) {

        System.out.println(field1);
        StringField1 = field1.getText();

        int index = Englishw.indexOfWord(StringField1);//this will give you the index of the word
        if (index == -1) {
            field2.setText("Word not found.");
            System.out.println(field2);

        } else {
            field2.setText(Frenchw.names2[index]);
            System.out.println("English Words=" + field1.getText());
            System.out.println("French Words =" + field2.getText());

            //setup Image
            Image = img.getIconImage();
            int index2 = img.indexOfImage(StringImage);
            JPanel1.add(img);


        }
    }
}
```

}

My two classes was for seting up images bu using JFame and imageArray: ImageInJframe and ImageImplement

public class ImageInJframe extends JFrame {

```
JFrame Frame;


Image[] pics;
String[] names = {"apple.jpg", "bags.jpg", "bathroom.jpg", "battled.jpg", "car.png",
        "chairs.jpg", "Computer.jpg", "family.jpg", "flowers.jpg", "god.jpg", "house.png", "map.jpg"
        , "men.jpg", "pencil.jpg", "sisters.jpg", "tomato.jpg", "watch.jpg", "women.jpg", "book.gif"};
final int NUM_PICS=names.length;
Graphics g;


public static void main(String args[])
{
    new ImageInJframe().start();
}


public void start()
{
    ImageImplement panel = new ImageImplement(new ImageIcon(String.valueOf(pics)).getImage());
    add(panel);
    setVisible(true);
    setSize(400,400);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setImage();
}

public void setImage() {


    pics = new Image[NUM_PICS];

}


public int indexOfImage(String userInput)
{
    for(int i=0;i<pics.length;i++)
    {
        if(userInput.equals(pics[i])){return i;}

    }
    return -1;
}
```

}

ImageImplement extend JPanel:

public class ImageImplement extends JPanel {

```
Image img;


public ImageImplement(Image img) {
    this.img = img;
    Dimension size = new Dimension(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null));
    setPreferredSize(size);
    setMinimumSize(size);
    setMaximumSize(size);
    setSize(size);
    setLayout(null);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
}
```

Comment: Please edit your post to include a description of expected behaviour and what you are seeing, along with any stacktrace

Comment: Painting occurs on demand, when your `paintComponent` is called, you are expected to repaint the current state of the UI. Maybe you should start by taking a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more detals about how painting works

Comment: 1) Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form. 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: I wanted to know how to setimage of each world enter in Jfield by using another class and and imageArray.

Comment: if you forget imageImplemnt and imageinJframe class.                         how can i creer a new class by using image array that will help me to make appear the image of each english word write in JField1 after click in JButton

Answer (score 2):

Painting occurs on demand, when your `paintComponent` is called, you are expected to repaint the current state of the UI. Maybe you should start by taking a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more detals about how painting works

Basically, from your `paintComponent`, you need to call `draw`, but you should pass it the `Graphics` context that was passed to the `paintComponent` method. It's dangerous and unwise to maintain a reference to a `Graphics` context you did not create

[image: Text]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new StringArrayEnglishWords());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class StringArrayEnglishWords extends JPanel {

        String[] names;

        public StringArrayEnglishWords() {

            EnglishWords();

        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            drawNames(g2d);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

        public void EnglishWords() {

            names = new String[16];
            names[0] = "Tomatoes";
            names[1] = "Chairs";
            names[2] = "Car";
            names[3] = "Computer";
            names[4] = "Flowers";
            names[5] = "Family";
            names[6] = "Sister";
            names[7] = "Husband";
            names[8] = "God";
            names[9] = "Book";
            names[10] = "Watch";
            names[11] = "Pencil";
            names[12] = "Bottle";
            names[13] = "Map";
            names[14] = "Wife";
            names[15] = "Bag";

        }

        public void drawNames(Graphics2D g2d) {
            for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
                g2d.drawString(names[i], 50, (1 + i) * 16);
            }
        }

        public int indexOfWord(String userInput) {
            for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
                if (userInput.equals(names[i])) {
                    return i;
                }

            }
            return -1;
        }

    }
}
```

You should also be careful when modifying the `Graphics` context, it is shared by all the components which are within the same window, in most cases, I find it useful to take a snapshot of the `Graphics` context (`Graphics#create`) and use that, then I don't need to remember to reset it when I'm done.

Applets are also a dead technology, the plugin has been deprecated and is no longer been supported and in most cases, is actively blocked by most browsers.  See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free) for more details

**Updated**

Change...

```
ImageImplement panel = new ImageImplement(new ImageIcon(String.valueOf(pics)).getImage());
add(panel);
```

to...

```
JLabel panel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(names[0]).getImage());
add(panel);
```

Assuming the image files are in the current directory where the program is been executed from, then it should work. If they are contained within the package with the class files, then you'll need to use `Class#getResource` to obtain a reference to the the image and pass the resulting `URL` to `ImageIcon`

Your `ImageImplement` panel is doing nothing, so even if it had a proper image to show, it wouldn't show anything.

`String.valueOf(pics)` makes no sense at all

You've posted a whole bunch of, what seems to be unrelated code and it's difficult to know what problem you're referring to

This...

```
ImageLabel.setIcon((Icon) img);
```

Makes no sense, `img` is an instance of `ImageInJFrame`, how is that even remotely related to a `Icon`?

I officially have no idea what you're trying to do

Comment: that means i have to change ImageinjFrame class into what you wrote?

Comment: i did the modifications you show me but i don't know if i have to delete one class?

Comment: and do you know how i can use only one classe for settingup images  and delete ImageInjframe and imageimplement?

Comment: how can you dou it by using imageArray

Comment: The real question is why? Why not just use a JLabel. It's much more complicated if want to generate a image per word, as you need to calculate the size of the text in advanced, before creating it

Comment: With all due respect, your codes a mess and it's hard to make heads and tails of what it's is trying to do